# Screen timeout for Ubuntu Server login screen

Tags: server, login, login-screen, screensaver

My server machine always has screen turned on on the login screen, which is shown right after the boot and where I have to input my login and password. There is no desktop environment. I wonder whether there is a way to set timeout for powering the screen off after some time of inactivity on the login screen. The autorun apps should continue to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a boot command line parameter `consoleblank` to do it. Save a copy of `/etc/default/grub` first, then add this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="consoleblank=450"
```

and remember to run `sudo update-grub` afterwards, then re-boot. the example is for 7.5 minutes. If you already have items on the command line then just add this one. Exmaple:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="ipv6.disable=1 consoleblank=450 intel_pstate=passive intel_pstate=no_hwp msr.allow_writes=on cpuidle.governor=teo"
```

Note that console blanking used to be the default, but it was changed some years ago now to not blank after some time by default.