# Turn off screen Ubuntu Server on Surface Pro 4

Tags: server, screen, 22.04, surface

I am running Ubuntu Server 22.04 on a Surface Pro 4 and I would like to turn off the screen after the server boots (or reboots). Currently, the only way I can do this is by running the command `setterm --blank 1 --powerdown 2` while I'm physically at the Surface, however I would like to be able to run this command remotely after logging in to the server via PuTTY. When run remotely, I get the message `setterm: terminal xterm does not support --blank`. I'm a beginner to Ubuntu and any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Screen timeout for Ubuntu Server login screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1323258/screen-timeout-for-ubuntu-server-login-screen)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Ubuntu server (no GUI), add `consoleblank=300` to your `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` line in your `/etc/default/grub` file, for a 5 minute no activity, then go blank setting. Keep a copy of your original `/etc/default/grub` file first, and remember to run `sudo update-grub` afterwards, then re-boot.

Example from my grub file and in context of other stuff on that line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="ipv6.disable=1 consoleblank=314 intel_pstate=active intel_pstate=no_hwp msr.allow_writes=on cpuidle.governor=teo"
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you, @Doug Smythies!

Comment: On iMac shows white blank. I want black blank.