# Screen never turns off

Tags: display

[image: Doesn't turn off]The screen never turns off.  I have attempted to adjust the power settings (Settings/Power/Power Saving/Blank Screen) to 1 minute, but it seems to be over ridden some how.  :/

In addition to the timeout, I would like a button (script?) that turns off the display output so my monitor auto switches to another input.

OS - Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS

What I've tried so far:

I found answers for Ubuntu Server w/ no GUI, but I have a GUI..  [Turn off screen Ubuntu Server on Surface Pro 4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406135/turn-off-screen-ubuntu-server-on-surface-pro-4)
I get the error, `setterm: terminal xterm-256color does not support --blank`, when running, `setterm --blank force`, locally from terminal.  I've tried, `setterm -blank 1`, as well, same result.

Comment: sudo apt install gnome-screensaver-command

Comment: Doesn't work.  --> E: Unable to locate package gnome-screensaver-command
I also tried screensaver apps but they only have screen saver settings (go figure) not screen off setting (they seem to assume your ubuntu screen off setting works..).