# How to find what is keeping screen from sleeping on Ubuntu Server 22.04?

Tags: server, suspend

I installed Ubuntu Server 22.04.3 LTS on an (old) iMac to use it in a headless capacity.

I want it to run with the lowest electricity usage possible, so I want the display to always be off, but I notice the screen is on a lot of the times I poke my nose in my server room.

I found this, related to making the boot screen sleep:
https://askubuntu.com/a/1406141/168006
I added that and it does sleep sometimes, but later it is on (whether or not I log in on the "head")

There is no mouse connected, just a keyboard (and no input on that keyboard).

```
owen:~$ systemd-inhibit --list
WHO                          UID USER PID    COMM            WHAT     WHY                                                       MODE 
ModemManager                 0   root 235936 ModemManager    sleep    ModemManager needs to reset devices                       delay
UPower                       0   root 235929 upowerd         sleep    Pause device polling                                      delay
Unattended Upgrades Shutdown 0   root 824    unattended-upgr shutdown Stop ongoing upgrades or perform upgrades before shutdown delay
```

I'm not quite sure how to interpret that. Is one of those items keeping the screen on? (How do I tell the duration of the delay?)

Is there something else I should check? Is there a way to just disable the screen entirely?