# how to turn screen off ubuntu server 20.04

Tags: server, 20.04, gnome-terminal, screen

ubuntu server 20.04 with no desktop only terminal after start the screen always on for input login information, how to make the screen off after some time and back to on again when hit any key?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Screen timeout for Ubuntu Server login screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1323258/screen-timeout-for-ubuntu-server-login-screen)