# How to set power saving settings in Ubuntu Server?

Tags: command-line, server, suspend, power-management

After about 10 minutes my monitor turns off, am wondering if I can set it to 30 minutes? I am on Ubuntu server with no GUI, just terminal.

I found a tutorial that completely turns off power management:

https://en-wiki.ikoula.com/en/Disable_Ubuntu_sleep_mode

not exactly what I want, I figure there is a config file somewhere?

Comment: As far as I know, the Ubuntu server default console blank time is that it never turns off. If you have 10 minutes, then I assume you set it at some point. Anyway, see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1323258/screen-timeout-for-ubuntu-server-login-screen). Many many releases ago, there was a default screen blank time of 5  or 10 minutes.

Comment: @DougSmythies Thank you, I forgot my brother helped my edit that grub file when we first installed.

Answer (score 0):

I set up a systemctl unit by creating a file in

`sudo vi /etc/systemd/system/console-blanking.service`

Then put these lines into the file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Enable virtual console blanking

[Service]
Type=oneshot
Environment=TERM=linux
StandardOutput=tty
TTYPath=/dev/console
ExecStart=/usr/bin/setterm -blank 60

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This will turn off the monitor after 60 minutes.